# Is there a way for an Arduino to flash another one without a computer?

Tags: programming, sd-card, flash

I am going to create a game console. The games will be in an SD card and an Arduino (or an Atmega chip) will read a hex file's contents to RAM and will flash it to another one. Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-sFQNIXde8) but here, the guy says that this only works for atmega328, and I am planning to use a ATSAM3X8E chip and also I am worried about the power levels (5v - 3v3).

Is there any way for me to use an Atmega chip like Atmega16u2 and use that to flash something like an ATSAM3X8E? If so, what protocol should I use and how may I implement it in my code?

Comment: That video isn't really relevant. Unless you want to waste two arduinos for this project, which is a bit wasteful. What you want to do is have the Arduino program itself. This is normally done via a bootloader (at least on the ATMegas). I found [a bootloader that updates it main program via a SD card](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bootloader-using-sdmmc-card)

Comment: As for the ATSAM, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960075/can-i-run-a-program-from-a-sd-memory-instead-of-flash-on-an-evaluation-board-em

Comment: @Gerben I want to *waste* two arduino's, actually I will use an Atmega16u2 for flashing the ATSAM3X8E from the sd card.

Comment: application on ATSAM3X8E  can write to flash without problems so it can update itself. Arduino has SDU library for SAMD21 to load sketch from SD card

Comment: @Juraj I need to display a GUI to ask the user about which program to flash.

Comment: On which Arduino do you want to run this GUI? The one doing the uploading, or the one running the game (which probably is the one with the screen and buttons)?

Comment: @Gerben on the one with a screen and some buttons. Like this: When the console powers up, the Atmega16u2 flashes gui.hex file to the ATSAM3X8E. Then, when user selects a game to load, ATSAM3X8E sends the name of the game to 16u2 and the 16u2 flashes the game to ATSAM3X8E.

Comment: I'd have the GUI write the new "programs" id to some file on the SD card and then reset the Arduino. The bootloader can then check this file, to see if it needs to program a new game to flash.

Comment: you don't need the 16u2

Comment: Good idea @Gerben , I may try that approach.

Comment: @Juraj how may I flash then?

Comment: read from SD and write to flash. of course there are many details to solve. the SDU library code checks at boot for new firmware binary on SD card and loads it to flash at address after the loader code, then executes it. this is close to what you want.